# EF6 AutoMapper6 Parent/Child different behavior

Tags: entity-framework-6, automapper

I just updated an entire WCF app from *EF4 / AutoMapper 1.1* to *EF6 / AutoMapper 6.0.0.2* and the behavior is not completely the same.

This doesn't work for me :
[Entity Framework - Add Child Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148585/entity-framework-add-child-entity)

**Before** :

```cs
child.Parent = parentObject
```

OR

```cs
parentObject.Children.Add(child)
```

had the same result in real time (while debugging == before SaveChanges), so I decided to use `child.Parent = parentObject` for the readability. `child.Parent = parentObject` added a child in parentObject automatically. The child was also added to the db.

**Now** : `child.Parent = parentObject` is not enough anymore (child is not added in the db), I have to add parentObject.Children.Add(child). Sometimes I need the link child.Parent = parentObject, so I have to write both lines. Can someone explain to me why it does not work anymore ?

Also :
I could write **before** :

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap< Patient, PATIENTENTITY >()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Gender, opt => opt.ResolveUsing< PatientGenderResolver >())
                .ForMember(dest => dest.REF_GENDER, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

where `dest.Gender` is the PK(int) and PatientGenderResolver find the id(int) of the Gender in the table REF_GENDER. This mapping was enough to set PATIENTENTITY.REF_GENDER in real time thanks to the Id resolver.

**Now** the id is set but PATIENTENTITY.REF_GENDER remains null.
Also I tried to set directly PATIENTENTITY.REF_GENDER with a resolver but it add a Gender in the table REF_GENDER...

So again, can someone explain to me why it does not work anymore ?

**EDIT**
Some precisions :
**Before :**

```cs
    patientEntity = Mapper.PatientToEntity(patientModel);
    //patientEntity.REF_GENDER is null
    Context.PATIENTENTITIES.AddObject(patientEntity);
    //patientEntity.REF_GENDER is set !
    Context.SaveChanges();
```

**Now :**

```cs
patientEntity = Mapper.PatientToEntity(patientModel);
//patientEntity.REF_GENDER is null
Context.PATIENTS.Add(patientEntity);
//patientEntity.REF_GENDER is still null !
//patientEntity.REF_GENDER = Context.REF_GENDER.Find(patientEntity.Gender);//I am obliged to add this line everywhere for every REF !
Context.SaveChanges();
```

My guess is that the two problems I have are related

**EDIT**
I just go back in my project. I now have EF6 and Automapper 1.1.
The problems are exactly the sames so I guess Automapper is not involved.

**EDIT**
I get around the REF_GENDER issue with

```cs
patientEntity = Mapper.PatientToEntity(patientModel, Context);
public PATIENT PatientToEntity(Patient patient, EntityContainer context)
{
    PATIENT entity = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Patient, PATIENT>(patient);
    if (patient.Id == null || patient.Id == Guid.Empty)
        entity.PatientId = Guid.NewGuid();
    else
        entity.PatientId = patient.Id;

    entity.REF_GENDER = context.REF_GENDER.Find(entity.Gender);

    return entity;
}
```

Apparently, the context has to be the same otherwise a new REF_GENDER is added to the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention it explicitly, but you didn't only move from EF 4 to 6, but also from `ObjectContext` to `DbContext`. That's a tremendous difference in behavior of the entity classes.

In the `ObjectContext` API the generated entity classes were stuffed with code that cooperated closely with the context they were involved in. A reference property like `child.Parent` would look like:

```cs
public Parent Parent
{
    get
    {
        return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<Parent>("model.FK_Child_Parent", "Parent").Value;
    }
    set
    {
        ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference<Parent>("model.FK_Child_Parent", "Parent").Value = value;
    }
}
```

So setting this property is setting the `Value` property of an `EntityReference<Parent>`. EF4.1's code isn't public, so we can only guess what happens inside. One thing is clear: it changes `child`s state into `Added` -- if `child` wasn't yet attached to the context.

Fortunately EF abandoned this rigid vendor lock-in when it released the `DbContext` API (in EF 4.1 no less). Now this generated property isn't anything but an auto-property:

```cs
public Parent Parent { get; set; }
```

This made it much easier to unify the database-first and code-first modes of working with EF. In fact, both code-first and database-first entity classes were POCOs now.

The price (if you like) is that EF can't keep as close a track of everything that happens as it could before. **Before**, all entity classes inherited from `EntityObject`, and EF could keep track of all of their interactions. The statement...

```cs
child.Parent = parentObject;
```

would draw the yet unknown `child` into the context through the attached `parentObject`.

**Now**, when someone sets `child.Parent`, no one but `child` knows what happened, not even `Parent`. Which means: there is no way *whatsoever* for EF to become aware of this change when its change tracker executes `DetectChanges` (as it does very frequently).

That's why using `DbContext` you have to add a new child to the context yourself, either by explicitly setting its state, or adding it to `context.Children`. Or by adding it to `parent.Children`, which is a change the change tracker *can* detect, if `parent` is attached.

Comment: You're right @Gert Arnold, move from ObjectContext to DbContext is a tremendous difference in behavior of the entity classes. Thx for your answer and your formatting. Finally I added child.Parent = parentObject AND parentObject.Children.Add(child) for my code to work again. And I set the ref's in the mapper like I wrote.

Comment: I just finished the migration after one week. I'm testing performance gain and in every cases it's worst than ef4 unlike https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/ef/ef6/fundamentals/performance/perf-whitepaper said... I'm quite disappointed :(

Comment: Yeah, that's unexpected. You could try asking a question about a specific case. Maybe, in the light of the above, there are some things you should do differently in EF6 as compared to EF4, for example using [foreign key associations instead of independent associations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12606948/861716).

Comment: 1 - I think I'm already using FK instead of independent association but I'm not sure. I mean, I already have one FK public int PrincipalEntity_Id { get; set; } (without [ForeignKey("PrincipalEntity_Id")]) AND one navigation property public Principal PrincipalEntity { get; set; } but I don't use the [ForeignKey("PrincipalEntity_Id")] because it's auto-generated code and I thought it was good enough for EF6 to understand

Comment: 2 - I'm investigating to improve loading performance. I just noticed with SQL Profiler that a "where query" use lazy-loading : just one select/where for the "highest" object. Then I noticed that AutoMapper make a lot of select/where while mapping because of lazy-loading. It doesn't seems very effective ! So I tried the .Include (many) methods in the main query : it's a multi join query that seems to be more effective to me. But then the mapping still does the same amount of select/where, so I wonder if AutoMapper is still justified ?

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question with sufficient details to answer it. I can't answer this from the info in your comments and it's also beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: 3 - Also I forgot... the performance are not worst, I just forgot about cold and warm  execution, at the end the results are quite the sames