# EF Core vs EF6: Save by adding navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-core-2.1

I encountered some different behaviour between EF6 and EF Core and would like to know if I could get the same behaviour in EF Core like in EF6, e.g. by changing some configuration.

```
public partial class Parent
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}

public partial class Child
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ParentId { get; set; }
  public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
  public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
  public virtual DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
  public virtual DbSet<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
    .HasOne(c => c.Parent)
    .WithMany(p => p.Childs)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);

  modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Childs)
    .WithOne(c => c.Parent);
}
```

The following code saves a new Child using EF6 but not using EF Core

```
var db = new MyContext();
var parent = db.Parents.First();

var child = new Child
{
  SomeProperty = "foobar",
  Parent = parent
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

What also works in EF Core is when I add the following, of course.

```
db.Childs.Add(child);
```

Edit: For the EF6 model `ObjectContext` and classes generated by EDMX have been used.

Comment: It's important to know which context type you're using in EF6. I assume it's `ObjectContext` and entity classes generated by an EDMX. With `DbContext` this wouldn't work either.

Comment: It's indeed `ObjectContext` and classes generated by an EDMX

Comment: The other way it's more explicit anyway: `parent.Childs.Add(child);`

Comment: OK, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52744550/861716) is a duplicate, it explains the difference between both types of contexts. The same applies to EF core's DbContext.

Comment: @GertArnold Excellent answer, VTCed as duplicate

Comment: @GertArnold Thank you very much